# CSS file not loading in Codeigniter

Tags: php, css

I am using codeigniter for one of my project. I am facing a problem with CSS. I am not able to load CSS. I am getting 404 error while loading the css. 
All my other functions are fine. Here is my view page-

```
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
  </head>
```

My .htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Rest all my functions are working fine. I mean I am able to access records via example.com/users/show  or example.com/users/show/

I think I am missing something. Can you please help me in this.

Comment: Meanwhile I changed my .htaccess with following - RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|CSS|JS|robots\.txt) but got the same issue

Comment: When you view the source of the webpage, does it show the correct URL ?  Do you get the css file when you type the url directly into the browser?

Comment: add bootstrap like this RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|bootstrap|robots\.txt) and try to access css directly, see what error you get

Comment: also post the source code of you css from generated page

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /Project Folder PATH
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```